# How can the runtime of following approach be O(N) and space-complexity be O(1)?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, data-structures

Can anyone explain how does the approach to the given problem described below operate in O(N) time and O(1) space?

Question: Given 2 sorted arrays, find the number of elements in common. The arrays are same length and each has all distinct elements.

Take following 2 arrays for example:

```
A: 13, 27, 35, 40, 49, 55, 59
B: 17, 35, 39, 40, 55, 58, 60
```

1. Do a linear search in B for A[0] = 13. Start at B[0] = 17. Stop at B[0] = 17. Not found
2. Do a linear search in B for A[1] = 27. Start at B[0] = 17. Stop at B[1] = 35. Not found
3. Do a linear search in B for A[2] = 35. Start at B[1] = 35. Stop at B[1] = 35. found
4. Do a linear search in B for A[3] = 40. Start at B[2] = 39. Stop at B[3] = 40. found
5. Do a linear search in B for A[4] = 49. Start at B[3] = 40. Stop at B[4] = 55. found

I am confused at the part where we are doing a linear loop for getting all elements for A making O(N) time already and then again doing a linear search in B to find the element. The liner search in B is picking up where the last one left off. Won't this make the time-complexity of the given approach O(N^2)? If not, why?

Comment: @JimMischel No, because you only search from where you left off in the previous step. At the end of the process, you will have visited each element in A and B exactly once, that's O(n). And the size of input data is never included in the space requirement of the algorithm.

Comment: Ah, I read it too fast. Yeah, it's just a merge stated in a different way. O(n), with O(1) extra space.

Comment: @JimMischel: So best-case O(N) and worst-case O(N^2)?

Comment: No. It's always O(n). The first suggestion is the right one: do the steps on paper and you'll see why.

Comment: @Milin Worst case is O(N), and so is best case.

Comment: So the inner loop for element search always takes constant amount of time?

Comment: @Milin That isn't the reason. A single iteration of the inner loop can be anything between 0 and N long. But the **sum** of the inner loop lengths is always exactly N.

Comment: So to iterate N elements from outer loop and searching N elements in worst-case in inner loop. Won't this make the time-complexity O(n^2)?

Comment: Stop looking at it locally.

Comment: @Milin Just grab a pencil and paper, you'll be amazed at how much easier things will be.

Comment: @Milin It is fair to say that the inner loop takes amortized constant time, because in N iterations of the outer loop the inner one will perform no more than N iterations cumulatively. One iteration may skip half the list, other ones may crawl one element at a time, but the total is not going to exceed N, because you always continue at the position where you left, always progress by at least one position, and never go back to previously visited positions.

Comment: @biziclop Tried. The Inner loop hardly exceeds 2 iterations as it compares the element for lower than or greater than the element. I am more inclined towards dasblinkenlight's explanation for amortized time. However consider this case.
**A: 13, 27, 35, 40, 49, 55, 59
B: 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20**
For above 2 arrays, the inner loop for element search for 27 will iterate through all elements of B, but it would be for 27 only. The inner loop for the rest of the element search would be one iteration only for comparison and exit the loop. 
What would be the time complexity for above case?

Answer (score 5):

This is a variation of [*Merge Algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm), except the output sequence is *not* being constructed, and you advance lists to the next position using linear search, rather than going one element at a time.

If N is the total number of elements in both lists, merge is O(N) in time and O(N) in space. The space requirement comes from the need to store the output sequence, which your algorithm does not do. Therefore, your algorithm remains O(N) in time, and becomes O(1) in space requirement.